# How to increase the sensitivity of UI Buttons in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, uibutton

I made a mobile trivia game with Unity. It's based on the European map and every country is associated with a transparent UI button as you can see from the figure. For the first 2 or 3 rounds of the game, buttons are working perfectly and they sense the touch input without requiring extra clicks. But after a few rounds, some buttons do not sense the touch input, hence their functions are not executed.
I checked if those buttons were inactive somehow but it was not the case. Although the button looks active, it just does not work. And I am sure that I clear the arrays after each round so I don't think there's an overflow either. I am stuck with this problem. Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

As you can see, the countries are covered by rectangular buttons and the anchors of the buttons are set to the center of the country. I, actually , do not think that it's about where the buttons are located. Because if it was the case, they wouldn't work in the beginning as well.

Answer (score 0):

These political maps (EU4/CK2-like) are done in another way. Use texture and texture color at (X, Y) where (X, Y) is pointer position converted to texture scale. Look here for more info: https://forum.unity.com/threads/procedural-generate-mesh-from-color-map.399611/

Comment: but i have a single color for all the map. They're all blue. I think using buttons can work too but i just don't get the reason why it becomes insensitive after a while. Do you know about that? @user2890234

Comment: no need to show user colored map. You can store this map in assets folder and only reference it when trying to grab pixel color at (X, Y) position, while rendering your blue map to user. Map would be a lot more accurate and every country would  trigger click exactly according to it's borders, not shitty boxes xD Don't know why you have a problem with sensitiveness, would be not simple to answer smth cause i didn't encountered this before and have no example